# Can one isolate processes on a 8086?

Tags: 8086

I've read that modern OSes rely on hardware-powered process isolation to prevent processes (and/or users) from clobbering each others' RAM. But on Intel processors, this hardware was first included in the 80286 (protected mode), so Linux required a minimum of a 80386 to run.

Was there a way to run a memory safe POSIX on a 8086 or 80286?

Comment: well on pure SW solution the only safe option I can think of would be interpreted processes ... so not compiled executables but interpretable source code would run instead... In such OS/Environment you could create memory protection but the result would be really slow .... in comparison to HW implementation + compiled executables

Comment: @Spektre - you can make a system safely run compiled code without hardware protection if you have a single compiler that's always used (so compile on installation, perhaps from bytecode), you trust that compiler not to have any bugs (!), and the language implemented by the compiler is memory safe.  Recent examples of this approach include Microsoft Singularity (where the compiler was an extended version of C#) and a number of systems based on Java.

Comment: @Jules: And not yet really "retro", but much older than your examples: the IBM AS/400. The AS/400 actually does both things you cite: native OS/400 code is delivered in bytecode and compiled by the OS on first execution. POSIX code is run in the PASE (Portable Application Solutions Environment, although the P is also often interpreted as "POSIX"), which provides a partially interpreted, partially cleverly implemented POSIX API.

Answer (score 27):

The short answer would be "No", since there is no way to prevent a user process from accessing privileged address space (of the OS or other processes) without some form of memory protection. Usually, this memory protection has to be implemented in hardware of the processor, such as you pointed out with 80286 protected mode.

Some alternatives would be:

1. A hardware implementation of memory protection outside of the 8086 microprocessor. This was done, for example, with the [Altos Series](http://chiclassiccomp.org/docs/content/computing/Altos/Marketing/Altos586Datasheet2.pdf).
2. A strict software convention for user processes that would (barring coding bugs) ensure they only access parts of memory they specifically "owned".

Since POSIX is built on the older C-standard for heap usage (i.e. malloc/free), it would be possible to have user processes that cooperate on an 8086, through these API's, to guarantee they only access their own memory. Of course, bugs being a reality, this would not be as good as hardware protection of memory. Systems such as the Amiga and Macintosh (using the Motorola 68000) that used this strategy of software convention suffered with stability problems created by memory access bugs.

Comment: "A hardware implementation of memory protection outside of the 8086 microprocessor. I don't know of any systems that did this." ... I just went looking, on the basis that it seemed that it would be reasonably simple to implement such a system so figured somebody must have done it, and found [this system](http://chiclassiccomp.org/docs/content/computing/Altos/Marketing/Altos586Datasheet2.pdf) (also described in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altos_586)).

Comment: @Jules Excellent find! I added a link to the answer.

Comment: You know you can just type in a memory-smashing x86 binary into vi right?

Comment: @Joshua Your point being? If you run it, the only person you're going to affect is yourself. You can't bring down a modern system with memory protection as an unprivileged user, and buggy programs generally can't bring down other unrelated programs running on the system either. At least, not if there are quotas for resource usage etc. - without those, something like a fork bomb is still possible!

Comment: @BrianH The AmigaDOS operating system (68000) provided for your option 2.  Even though any process could get at any other process' memory there were a great many well-behaved programs which would share data in well-defined, efficient, cooperative ways.  Pre-dating that was classic FORTH, which allowed for a multi-process, multi-user environment in as low as 56 kbytes of RAM, running on various 8- and 16-bit machines. It was simply a matter of following the rules.  Yes, one user *could* crash everybody, but it was more fun pushing the thing to its limits.

Comment: Oh. I misread the answer as implying you could have actual security by restricting what binaries can be run.

Comment: The Wikipedia page about [Xenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenix) also mentions [Seattle Computer Products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle_Computer_Products) and Intel's "System 86" which seems to imply the later also had an MMU (Intel did sell special boards with MMU).

Comment: You could emulate an MMU, but it would be horrifically slow.

Answer (score 19):

A computer using an 8086 can provide memory protection by using an external memory management unit.  This would be a chip or a circuit that sits between the CPU and the memory and provides an additional layer of memory translation, sends interrupts if out-of-range memory is accessed, and so on. I don't know if this was commonly done on the 8086 (I've never seen such a system described, but then I've not looked for one either), but was very common for workstations based on early revisions of the 68000.

(Edit: at least [some systems were produced that used this approach](http://chiclassiccomp.org/docs/content/computing/Altos/Marketing/Altos586Datasheet2.pdf), although as @RossRidge points out in the comments it was a little easier on the 68000 due to specific support designed into the processor, which is probably why it was more common there.)

For an 80286, the standard 286 protected mode provides all the isolation that you'd need to run a POSIX compliant operating system with memory safety.

(It wouldn't be a very good POSIX system, because memory allocations would need to be limited to 64K to fit inside segment limits, but POSIX allows for sizes to be limited as low as [_POSIX_SSIZE_MAX, which is defined as 32KiB](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html), so this is fine)

There have been a number of Unix-like operating system that run on the 8086 and 80286, including Minix, which is usually considered the forerunner of Linux (it is the system that Torvalds used at the time he developed the first versions of Linux and influenced the early development quite a bit) and Xenix.  There is also a port of Linux to 16-bit systems called [ELKS](https://github.com/jbruchon/elks), although I don't know whether it supports memory protection or not (looking at the source suggests it probably does, but I've never really done anything with it so can't be sure).

Comment: The 68000 had one feature that made MMUs work that the 8086 didn't have, separate user and supervisor modes.  There's no way for an MMU on a 8086 to distinguish between memory accesses of different processes. I don't know if POSIX actually requires process isolation. MINIX ran on 8086s.

Comment: @RossRidge - an 8086 MMU can easily distinguish the location of running code (the S1 and S0 lines are both low during code fetch cycles), so could identify privileged code from that.  It could also use the same approach to prevent arbitrary jumps into privileged code.  It'd be quite tricky, I agree, but not beyond possibility.

Comment: (in fact, you'd probably set a specific location in memory that when fetched as executable code triggers a switch to supervisor mode; that'd be fairly simple to implement; then you'd vector system calls and interrupts through that point to make sure they ran as supervisor mode. Dammit... going to have build an 8086 system with memory protection now. As if I don't have enough projects!).

Comment: @Jules: I think the best approach would probably be to make the bottom chunk of memory read-only in user tasks, and have any interrupt that occurs while in user state trigger an NMI for some number of cycles and then switch to supervisor state; the NMI handler would run from the initially-read-only chunk of storage at the bottom of  the address space while it starts saving registers to a nearby chunk of storage that belongs to the task, but which it would be allowed to overwrite.  If a user process leaves SS/SP in a garbage state, switching to the OS and back may execute code...

Comment: ...at some meaningless address, but such code wouldn't be able to do anything not explicitly allowed by the OS.

Comment: The original 68000 (fixed in later processors) however couldn't support virtual memory without doing some external hacks as the instructions weren't restartable after the bus fault.

Comment: @PeterI: A solution for that was to have a system with two 68000 processors, only one of which was allowed to run at any given time.  A page fault would stall one CPU and wake up the other, which could then process it.  Perhaps a similar approach could work using the 8086.  Probably easier than any other approach for allowing tasks to have some of their memory swapped to disk out at any given time and having it "transparently" get swapped back in, but a system may be useful even without such abilities.

Comment: Xenix wasn't just "Unix-like", [it _was_ a Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenix). It ran on a number of 8086-systems with external MMU although there also was a version for MMU-less systems later on.

Comment: @supercat - it wouldn't even necessarily need to be an 8086.  In a system with an 8089, for example, I suspect that would be capable of handling page faults along with its other tasks (which usually included disk control).

Answer (score 12):

Technically yes because the 8086 instruction set is Turing-complete. [Here](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/124287-the-worlds-slowest-linux-pc) is Linux running very slowly on an ARMv5 emulation on an 8-bit RISC microcontroller (also mentioned [here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4871/75)). But if you want process isolation, I would look for other, less extreme solutions first!

Comment: Ah, the [Turing tarpit](http://wiki.c2.com/?TuringTarpit) argument. Nice. :)

Comment: @Jules For completeness if nothing else.

Comment: @MartinRosenau That's a fundamental misunderstanding of Turing completeness. For a system to be Turing complete, it only needs to be able to _compute_ anything. It doesn't need any other capabilities.

Comment: @duskwuff This is exactly what I wanted to say. I was writing my comment because **many** people argue with Turing completeness in situations where it would not be allowed.

Answer (score 4):

I would say no. Even if external memory protection hardware is added, the processor lacks the concept of a user and supervisor or privileged state. As a result, there's no way to stop a program from disabling interrupts or accessing I/O ports, like those in the MMU.

Now if we set aside the need to isolate a malicious program, the MMU might be enough. Only problem with that thinking is that buggy programs can be pretty malicious even if the author is not.

So it would seem that we are back to no!

If you want process isolation, you need something more modern and a well written operating kernel.

Comment: An 8086 MMU would have to track whether code executing was privileged or not by itself, but that would likely not be hard.  It could prevent access to IO ports simply by not allowing the processor to use them in user mode; similarly, disabling interrupts isn't actually a huge issue: it could use an NMI instead of a regular interrupt; privileged code could disable and enable the use of NMI by communicating with the MMU rather than using the internal processor interrupt controls.  Messy, but workable.

Comment: To clarify, the 8086 does not have a user mode, so there's no way for the mmu to know what privilege level applies. Further, the vast majority of peripherals will simply not work using the NMI. Plus there are times (like critical sections) where it is essential to mask interrupts.  The best answer I have seen would be to run the code in some sort of virtual machine which would enforce the needed rules. At that point I don't see the point of using an 8086. One might as well run the emulator in a browser using JavaScript. It would run a lot quicker!

Comment: there may not be a processor supported user/supervisor mode switch, but there's no reason an MMU can't implement one itself, switching to supervisor mode (for example) either on a hardware interrupt or when execution reaches a certain point in the code (which can be easily determined because the 8086 has status lines that indicate whether a read operation is for data or code).  Masking interrupts is not the only way to provide critical sections, either (e.g. the LOCK# signal could be used to provide atomic operations by causing the MMU to forcible delay any pending interrupt)

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand what you mean by "the vast majority of peripherals will simply not work using the NMI" -- I don't see how the peripheral would care (or even identify) which of the two possible methods is used to identify to the processor that attention is required.  An NMI and an external register used to indicate which IRQ line caused the interrupt is entirely equivalent, as far as I can see, to the standard INTR line behaviour. Other than not signalling the INTA line, and only providing a single vector, the behaviour of the NMI line on the 8086 is exactly equivalent to INTR...

Comment: ... and both of those can be trivially emulated by a simple piece of hardware and a small addition to the operating system code.

Comment: @Jules: Using INTR would be better than NMI except for one problem: I don't know any nice way to protect against the possibility of a CLI instruction killing the system.

Comment: In most 8086 systems, interrupts are interfaced to the CPU via an 8259A controller. That controller very much requires an INTA input to work. Forcing the use of NMI would break that controller chip too. At some point you've got to admit that this idea has turned into a zombie. Long passed the time to throw in the towel.

Comment: @PeterCamilleri: When discussing approaches that would require hardware support, I see no reason not to assume that things like interrupts would be handled using the same chips as would be used in a 'normal" system.

Comment: @Jules The possibility to check if the CPU performs code or data access is not even necessary: A CPU can only perform a limited number of data accesses before a code access is done. You can imagine patterns of memory accesses which are only possible if the PC (8086: CS:IP) points to a certain memory location. The MMU "just" has to detect this pattern if the CPU does not have support for distinguishing code and data access...

Comment: This is getting silly, but I just had to point out that the 8086 has block operations that can perform many thousands of data cycles without any intervening instruction cycles.

Comment: @PeterCamilleri: Later x86 processors can perform block-move operations without re-fetching them, but I don't think the 8088 or 8086 can.  My recollection is that on the 8088, if CX is non-zero and the direction flag is clear, a `rep movsw` will load bytes from `si` and `si+1`, store bytes to `di` and `di+1`, add two to si and di, subtract one from CX, subtract 2 from PC, and clear the prefetch queue.

Answer (score 4):

The 8086,80186,8088 and 80188 all lacked any real memory protection although switching segment registers would protect against accidental overwriting.    The 80286 did support protection so a POSIX OS with hardware enforced memory protection could be written.

The NEC V20 and V30 were 8086 clones with a 8080 emulation mode.  Since it wouldn't be able to address more than 64K in 8080 mode one could presumably write a POSIX OS where the kernel ran in 8086 mode while userspace ran in 8080 mode switching between them to make system calls.   Presumably it would still be possible to address the first 256 I/O ports directly which would mean user process could talk directly to some fairly important hardware if the V20/V30 were embedded in a standard IBM PC clone.

Answer (score 2):

The 8086 is a 16-bit processor.  One possibility for implementing some form of process isolation is to use the processor's segment registers (CS, DS, SS, ES).  These allow a process's stack (SS), heap (DS, ES), and code (CS) reside in specific 64kB areas of a 1MB address space.  This works by left shifting the 16-bit segment register by four bits and adding to that the 16-bit stack pointer (`SS << 4 + SP`), instruction pointer (`CS << 4 + IP`), or data address (e.g. `CS << 4 + SI`), to obtain the 20 bits of the physical address.

Thus, through a suitable segment register setup one can isolate a process to at most 64kB, provided the process follows the *convention* of not altering the segment registers.  For the requirements of C programs, where the heap and the stack must be addressable through the same 16-bit pointers, this convention restricts them to 64kB of data and 64kB of code.  Although this might sound overly restrictive, remember that early Unix run on a PDP-11 with 64kB of RAM.  Consequently, providing a 1MB memory for multiple processes with up to 64kB of code and 64kB of data is more than generous.

Furthermore, by manipulating segment registers and copying memory regions, a supervisor program can dynamically readjust memory regions as processes are created and destroyed in a way that's transparent to running processes.  Early versions of Andrew Tannembaum's [MINIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINIX) operating system relied on some of these ideas.

Comment: In order for this to provide real protection the code must not be allowed to change segment registers, disable interrupts, or invoke `IN` and `OUT` instructions. Those restrictions cannot be enforced in hardware but validation of the user code before transferring control would be possible. Similar just-in-time code validation is used in other places such as Java byte code, some versions of VM Ware, and the NaCl sandbox.

Comment: Minor nitpick: C does not have a requirement that the heap and stack be addressable through the same pointers. An *implementation* that chooses to make pointers only 16 bits wide must have coincident stack and data segments because there is no way to encode the required segment and a segment address in 16 bits but you don't have to have 16 bit pointers on an 8086.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it's not easy. There are at least two possible approaches:

## Option 1: software virutalization

This one is the canonical/classical solution. Essentially, you write an emulator/interpreter for some sort of virtual machine that *does have* kernel/user privilege modes and memory protection. You need to ensure (or assume) your interpreter has no vm-escape bugs.

## Option 2: validating programs

Write the program-loader not to accept arbitrary 8086 machine code, but instead only a highly structured subset with enforcement of memory safety. This requires designing such a subset, and again you need to ensure or assume your implementation doesn't have bugs that break the necessary invariants.

Either way, to do POSIX or even something POSIX-like you're going to need **lots** of supplemental memory. There's no way to implement POSIX in the main memory size supported by the 8086, and both of these options will greatly further increase the required memory (and decrease speed).

Comment: "There's no way to implement POSIX in the main memory size supported by the 8086" ... this is almost certainly incorrect.  Xenix ran on the 8086 and while it [was not POSIX compliant](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/how-posix-compliant-is-xenix) it did include a large majority of POSIX's most complex functions.  The "ELKS" port of Linux (see my answer above) also includes a large proportion of POSIX support, and reportedly runs in < 256KiB, including X11 support.

Comment: ... furthermore, POSIX is a formalisation and extension of the System V Interface Definition, which was based on System V Release 2.  SVR2's target machine was the DEC VAX 11/780, and I believe ran on the minimum configuration of that system, which is to say in 128KiB RAM. AT&T's 3B1 minicomputer (designed to run SVR3, the release of Unix that was most recent at the time POSIX was written, I believed) was available in a 512KiB configuration.  I see nothing that suggests 1MiB of RAM isn't plenty for supporting full POSIX compliance (not to mention that bank switching could easily extend that).

Comment: @Jules: I don't have the numbers in front of me right now, but having implemented much of it myself, I've done some casual estimates on lower bounds for the possible size, and it doesn't look good. On top of that (which didn't consider 8086 limitations), with POSIX requiring at least 32-bit int, just the arithmetic and argument-passing overhead is going to blow up size a good bit. And with no fpu, the math library and softfloat will be quite large.

Comment: 32-bit int is only required by POSIX.1-2001, I believe.  Earlier versions allowed 16-bit ints.  I have here a copy of an 8086 "math.h" library including software emulation which is less than 20KiB in size.  Admittedly, it doesn't contain all of the functions in the POSIX libm (it only has double versions and not float, and is missing a few of the less common functions).  The full version would, I suspect, fit in around 50KiB, which isn't exactly a huge problem.

Comment: Although I like your idea of validating code on load before running it, I wonder how could this be done in practice, considering the halting problem & stuff. I mean, such validation might be equivalent to actually running the program :q  If you simply search through it for jumps & segment loads, I can easily concoct a self-modifying code that produces such machine instructions somewhere on the fly and runs them, or a XORed piece of code that unXORs at runtime, etc., basically fooling your loader and breaking the protection. So I'm still not convinced it could work in practice.

Comment: @SasQ: Halting problem is not relevant to this. You don't care what the overall flow is or whether the program halts, only that each memory access, individually, is of some form you can guarantee is memory-safe in the sense you need. For instance one stupid way to do this might just be disallowing any insns that can modify the segment registers, limiting access to the process's kernel-assigned segments. That's glossing over a bit like the need to determine that there are no jumps to mid-insn (in which case an insn could be interpreted differently)...

Comment: ...but that can be solved statically for direct jumps. For indirect jumps you have to impose some requirement on their structure (disallowing arbitrary indirect jumps). This is a bit of a pain, but doable. In a worst case you could disallow them entirely and replace them with a "syscall" (software interrupt) to request the kernel do a validated indirect jump for you.

Comment: I think the halting problem _is_ sort of relevant, because in order to find naughty instructions on load, a naïve scan through the code might be insufficient to find them due to all sort of tricks that can hide them from that scan and unhide them only at runtime. You would have to "interpret the code" before execution to find out if some instructions break your protections at runtime (think self-modifying code; if code is read-only: think indirect jumps to addresses calculated at runtime etc.) which is what the halting problem is about (interpreting code to see if it will do something or not).

Comment: @SasQ: There's no self-modifying code because you disallow load of segment registers and code is in a different segment. (If you're not disallowing load of segment registers there are other ways to achieve this but it's more complicated and not important for my PoC here.) There is no requirement to interpret code only to disassemble it, as described above. Indirect jumps do require some special care but you simply impose structure on them and enforce that structure when checking the disassembly.

Answer (score 1):

The Minix operating system implemented Virtual Memory Management on 8086 in software. Minix source code is available.

Answer (score 0):

> Can one isolate processes on a 8086?
>
> Was there a way to run a memory safe POSIX on a 8086 or 80286?

To start with, 8086 or 286 (non protected mode), usually run DOS and thus only one process.

And the general answer would be **no** ...

... but it is possible to run either CPU in [single step mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_flag).

Sure, it'll slow down operation quite a lot, but for testing purpose it's a great way to monitor everything. With a few additional restrictions the downside can be (somewhat) kept in check. By making all used memory segments non overlapping and 64 KiB in size, the ISR only needs to check if an instruction loading a segment register is about to be executed, any only do detailed checking then, otherwise directly return.

I used that when searching for a memory problem in a rather complex communication application. In fact, with this (and other) optimizations it was fast enough to even cape up with average work load, fine to have it running for long enough to finally catch the bug - about 3 weeks later.

Bottom Line: Yes, it's possible, but you want to do it a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can with external hardware. The MC6829 MMU for the 6809 is a good example of how to do it. It detects when the CPU answers an interrupt request (software or hardware), and puts itself into a supervisor state when it can be modified. The you touch the "fuse register" just before a return from interrupt to enter user state, where it's completely invisible to the programmer and CPU.

Comment: Beside that an 8086 isn't a 6800 and no 6829, what is the relation to the question asked?

Comment: I gave an example of how such external hardware can work. The only requirement is that the CPU somehow signals an Interrupt Acknowledge cycle, which the 8086 does. Hence the same solution can be used.